# gmail oauth2 invalid grant on appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gmail-api, oauth-2.0

As it usually happens, the customer changed their G Suite email password which we were using for sending out emails (on Java@AppEngine). The token has been revoked as expected, and we managed to get everything working on DEV and UAT environments, however PROD for some reason still getting the infamous "invalid grant". I wonder if there's some caching that holds to original Credential in the datastore? Stackdriver doesn't let evaluate the method call so can't see what's inside. We suspect it has something to do with cache but restarting GAE instance (by redeploying) hasn't resolved the issue. Any suggestions are welcome!

This is a bit from the logs:

> Caused by: com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400
>   {
>     "error" : "invalid_grant"
>   }
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570)
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
>       at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
>       at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it all worked this time, but this sequence seem to work:

1. pause the queues to avoid "old" token being cached again and again when it tries to resend the email
2. delete the stored credential from datastore
3. flush the memcache
4. re-configure your app to authorize it to have access to your gmail (essentially get the new credential to your datastore)
5. resume the queue and enjoy